# Linq to Entites - Project Entity Association to List of Interfaces

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a scenario where I would like to query a Context containing two `EntityObjects` and cast the results to strongly typed Lists of interfaces.

**The Entity Objects**

```
public class CompanyEntity : EntityObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EntityCollection<StaffEntity> Staff { get; set; }
}

public class StaffEntity : EntityObject
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**The Domain Objects**

```
public class Company : IOrganisation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IPerson> Staff { get; set; }
}

public class StaffMember : IPerson
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**The Interfaces**

```
public interface IOrganisation
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<IPerson> Staff { get; set; }
}

public interface IPerson
{
    string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

If I ignore the `StaffEntity` and just query the `CompanyEntity`, casting it to a `List<IOrganisation>` is straight forward as follows:

```
List<IOrganisation> orgs = (from c in context.Companies
                            select new Company
                            {
                                Name = c.Name 
                            }).ToList<IOrganisation>();
```

However I run into problems when I want to query both `EntityObjects` and project the associated `StaffEntity` objects to `StaffMember` domain objects, then cast them to `List<IPerson>` so they can be assigned to the `Staff` property of the `Company` Object.

I have tried a number of things, the closest I got was as follows, however at runtime EF did not like the call `.ToList<IPerson>()`:

```
List<IOrganisation> orgs = (from c in context.Companies.Include("Staff")
                            select new Company
                            {
                                Name = c.Name,
                                Staff = (from s in c.Staff
                                         select new StaffMember
                                         {
                                             FullName = s.FullName,
                                         }).ToList<IPerson>()
                            }
                            into results
                            select results).ToList<IOrganisation>();
```

So I basically need to retrieve a nested object graph of Lists of Interfaces with a LINQ to Entities query. The reason I need the domain objects as lists of interfaces is because they get passed into other assemblies that have no reference to the concrete domain objects or the Entity Framework, however they do have a reference to the interfaces they implement. Furthermore, it is not appropriate for the `EntityObjects` to implement the interfaces, so I would like to see if the question I am asking is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. EF was not able to do what I wanted, so I retrieved my `EntityObjects` using the `AsEnumerable()` method and from there I was able to use LINQ to Qbjects to do what I wanted on the `IEnumerable` collection.

The working solution is as follows

```
List<IOrganisation> orgs = context.Companies.Include("Staff")
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(c => new Company
                               {
                                   CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                                   Staff = c.Staff.Select(s => new StaffMember
                                                  {
                                                      FullName = s.FullName
                                                  }).Cast<IPerson>().ToList()
                               }).Cast<IOrganisation>().ToList();
```

Comment: btw, ["MEF" means this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) - Entity Framework is just [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)